Difference between future use of てくる・なってくる vs base form・なる for state change verbs
For example, imagine a doctor saying:
医者：すぐによくなってくるでしょう。
How would this be different from simply saying
医者：すぐによくなるでしょう。
Similarly, if someone said
寒くなってくる季節。
How is this different from
寒くなる季節。
Or for a third example, how about:
株価が上がってくるらしい
vs
株価が上がるらしい
My base instinct is that the first shows some sort of personal involvement / investment in the situation whereas the other doesn't necessarily, but I can't rule out that maybe there's some other implication I'm not noticing (does なってくる imply 徐々に ?).
Anyway, what are the implications?

I just answered you another question, in which the answer is similar so I am keep it simple here.
The word "くる” put emphasis on changes.  In your examples, that will be the change in health, temperature, and stock prices respectively.

So for the doctor example, the one with 〜てくる emphasised on the process of becoming good.  In my opinion I think it feels slower.  Compare to English:
"You will be better soon" vs "You will become better soon"
"become better" feel more lengthy, no?

On the temperature example, again it emphasised on the changing of the temperature, the approaching of the colder weather.  The base meaning is the same.
My comment would be 寒くなってくる季節 can feel softer and more elegant, compare to 寒くなる季節, which sounds more descriptive.  Note that I am NOT sure if everyone would feel the same.  Again this is quite nuanced.

On the stock example, the 〜てくる feels slower with the same reasoning.
So, I suppose you can say that in some cases 〜てくる equates in functions with 徐々に (slowly), as in the examples you provided.  I don't think "implies 徐々に" is correct in all cases since 次回はもっと勉強してきます does not feel slow, in fact it feels faster than 次回はもっと勉強していきます.

See my other answer on your similar question for my rationale: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/105134/for-the-まで-から-time-based-meanings-of-てくる-and-ていく-are-they-grammatically-requir

I am not sure how to interpret your examples other than the literal "study more and go/come":次回はもっと勉強してきます ・次回はもっと勉強していきます.

The key point is that てくる put focus on the change and progress.  As a result it can give actions a slower feeling.  There are not many differences other than that for the sentence pairs that you have provided.

As a take away you can probably just ignore their differences.  Even in English there are such nuanced expressions: "quiet good" vs "good" vs "very good".  Not necessarily useful to know.
