For the まで・から time based meanings of てくる and ていく , are they grammatically required? If not, how do the meanings change?
Given these grammar point example sentences:
＜現在から未来へ＞
これからは一緒に生きていこう。
これからも頑張っていきましょう！
＜過去から現在まで＞
これまで会社員としてずっと生きてきた。
10年間頑張ってきたバレエをやめた。
What would change if I instead said:
これからは一緒に生きよう。
これからも頑張りましょう！
これまで会社員としてずっと生きた。
10年間頑張ったバレエをやめた。
Would the latter two even be grammatical / natural?

Rationale
Instead of thinking about the grammar, as a general rule of thumb, I believe focusing on the meaning you are trying to convey is more useful and important for language learning.
Otherwise, it is a common "pitfall" that we start memorising grammar as prescriptive rules, without knowing that these rules are fluid in the first place.

Answer to difference in meaning
Now, the words "くる”　and "いく" are used in Japanese when you want to put emphasis on changes.  In your specific use case that will be the passage of time.
Therefore, the answer to your first question would be that by using "くる”　and "いく", it will have a sense of continuity.

Meaning: From now on, lets live on together.

これからは一緒に生きよう -> sounds ok

vs

これからは一緒に生きていこう -> sounds way better if you are speaking at a wedding, as you will keep doing this for a long time (forever).


Answer to grammatical and natural sounding
１.これまで会社員としてずっと生きた。
Because of my stance on grammar, I don't think this is grammatically "wrong" per se.  However, it does a bit off.
The reason being you used "これまで" and "ずっと", which put emphasis on the passage of time BUT then you say 生きた, which breaks the congruence.  It will sound less annoying and natural if you say ずっと生きてきた。
Alternatively, you can replace 生きてきた with 生き続けた, in which 続けたmeans "continuously", hence keeping the unity.
２. 10年間頑張ったバレエをやめた
Again with the same reasoning, it sounds off.  This time I will approach it differently as say if you can drop the emphasis of 10年間, then it will be congruent.  For instance you can say the same thing as: "学生時代に学び始めたバレエをやめました" (assuming 学生時代 is 10 years ago)

Comments
Again I don't believe in strict grammar rules, new ways of using languages are being invented every day.  (e.g. さ入れ言葉、ら抜き言葉…)  Do keep in mind, that some will look at such speech as uneducated, ill-mannered, as in English if you are not "posh".
My answers on being natural are based on my experience as of [2024-07-19], who knows what will happen in 10 years!
If you go on and search for the incongruent forms, I am sure you can find some Japanese already using them that way, albeit not so much, for now.

So does てきた and ていく imply 続けた・ 続ける ?

@Moon_Atomizer I am not sure what you mean by "imply", I would rather say it emphasised it for the examples that you have provided.  This is not necessarily true for all case though, because 太陽が昇ってきた emphasise on the change instead.  It translates to "The sun (started) rising"
